# How to load named module in requirejs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have an optimized module by requiredJs. I want to load that module in my Router. I was able to do that  if the module is not optimized but after optimizing, the router doesn't work anymore. Here is how the optimized module looks like and the router code

Optimized module:

```
define('fullpage/pages/participant/ParticipantJoin',[
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',    
    'translator',

    // Using the Require.js text! plugin, we are loaded raw text
    // which will be used as our views primary template
    'text!fullpage/pages/participant/templates/participantJoinTemplate.html',

], function($, _, Backbone, ParticipantInvitation, ParticipantInfo, Translator, template){
    var ParticipantJoinView = Backbone.View.extend({

.... more code
```

The router code

```
var app_router = new AppRouter;
        app_router.on('route:invite', function(inviteId){


            require([
                'pages/participant/ParticipantJoin'
            ], function(ParticipantJoinView) {

                var participantJoin = new ParticipantJoinView({
                    inviteId: inviteId
                });

            });
        });
```

The error is that the ParticipantJoinView is null. I don't know why that module is not loaded. How can I make it loaded?

Thanks,

Comment: Whats with the fullpage/ ? Why do you have it in one place and not the other?

Comment: try to define `baseUrl` in `requirejs.config` + be sure u return `ParticipantJoinView` from `pages/participant/ParticipantJoin` module